# Jmeter error occurred when running jmeter.bat

Tags: jmeter

just download and extracted jmeter on my pc.
when i double click jmeter.bat, this error occurred

```
An error occurred: class com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap over
rides final method setMap.(Ljava/util/Map;)V
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

why is jmeter have to do with com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap.
any idea what is wrong with my environment?

im using 
apache-jmeter-2.11 and java version "1.7.0_51"

i have also extracted 5 plugins: standard set, extras with lib set, extras set, WebDriver set and Hadoop set.

updated:

i sort of found out the problem. It is because i din't extract the plugins in correct order.

it must follow this order: Extras > ExtrasLib > Hadoop > Standard > WebDriver when extracting the plugins into jmeter directory. Then the jmeter can be started without error.

Comment: please give us the output of "java -version". And do you know the version of your jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error may be related to the presence of 2 different versions of GUAVA library.

I suppose you are using some third party JMeter plugin (possibly JMeter-Plugins + Selenium Driver).
You may find this interesting:

- http://www.simplehooman.co.uk/2013/03/jmeter-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-jmeter-gui-util-menufactory/

Comment: thx for this. i sort of figured it out the problem from your answer.